# A strange bug for Devexpress XPInstantFeedbackSource , any idea?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Don't need to go so far, just install Devexpress 11.2.5 and run the GridDemo( Start -> All Programs -> Developer Express v2011 vol 2 -> Components -> Demos -> WPF -> GridDemo)
now go to the sample "Linq To SQL Server" , you would see a window asking for SOL connection , just keep the default if you have an SQL installed on your machine or use .\SQLExpress for the SQL Server field , then press "Generate table and Start Demo". 
I have a Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Due CPU 2.2Ghz with 4.0GB Ram with a Windows 7 64bit installed on it, The issue is that when i start the demo it always consumes 8 to 12 percent of my CPU usage and when i scroll the grid it'll grow up to 50-70% , and f i minimize the window i'\ drop down bellow 1%, my customer has a Intel Celeron computer when this demo is executed on there computer it consumes about 60% to 80% of there CPU usage , that dose not seem ordinary
, am i missing something or could this be a bug for Devexpress ?

Comment: Try the DevExpress forums/support. They offer complimentary evaluation support. As long as it's not *constant* CPU I'd say it'd "okay" (what else would a CPU do if not being used? ;-). E.g. if it goes back to minimal CPU after launch/scrolling operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I replaced XPInstantFeedbackSource with XPServerCollectionSource and the cpu usage got fixed. Strange bihaviour!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. This data source loads only objects that are requested by the grid (i.e. currently visible ones). That allows the grid to be loaded immediately with minimal CPU usage. When you start scrolling the grid, XPInstantFeedbackSource will start asynchronous data loading for rows that becomes visible and then will update grid's visible cells. It may takes some CPU resources. If you quickly scroll the grid, XPInstantFeedbackSource will load values of the key column for all grid rows. The information is necessary to determine what object to load when a particular row becomes visible. This operation may take time, but is executed only once. XPInstantFeedbackSource caches objects in an XPO session. So, an object, once loaded, is retrieved from the cache when accessed the next time.
Anyway the detailed explanation can be taken via the [Official DevExpress Support channel](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question).